# Website files location. Parent vs children

Tags: php, html, web

I am building a website and would like to ask something about best practices when having pages in different folders.

In my case, I would like to have a page in `../store/` and I have called it index.php.

This page loads external content, for example, the Header which is stored in the parent directory `../` along with some other pages. These pages loaded are used by other pages located in other subfolders.

The question is : Is it a better practice to have the Header (for example) replicated in each of the subfolders where an page is stored and will be using it?

Meaning I would call the header as `header.php`. Or is it better to have just 1 header in the parent and call it every time as `../header.php` ?

------------ UPDATE

In my site, I have an `index.php` in the parent directory. This `index.php` has a include that calls adds `commonItems/header.php`. At the same time, this header.php has a `<?php include("commonItems/menu.php"); ?>` to add the menu.

Then there is a folder in the parent that is called `store/` in which I have another `index.php` which also adds `../commonItems/header.php`. However, in this case, the header is added properly but the menu.php does not show up....

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: My first impression is that it'd be easier to maintain by having just a single `header.php` in the root folder, but it's pretty open-ended without more details on the purpose of your site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in having multiple `php` pages with the same content in different folders, especially if you are going to use them across the website.

In case of changes/maintainability, you'll have to make changes across all the folders where these files are located, which would make it very difficult to maintain.

So, if you use a file across various pages, might as well, put it in one place and call it from across the website.

To call them, I usually prefer to define a constant and use that, so :

```
define('COMMON', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'common/');
...
require COMMON . 'header.php';
```

Comment: And is it better to call these common files as `../commonFiles/header.php` or shall I rather specify the complete path like `http://www..../commonFiles/header.php` ?

Comment: If you `include/require` them, use something like : `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'common/header.php';`

Comment: Please see UPDATE in my question

Comment: @samyb8 : Check the last part of my answer, about the constant `COMMON` you should use it that way to ensure that the paths are fixed, not relative.

Comment: Should this work: `$pathCommonItems = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; $path= "/httpdocs/"; $pathCommonItems= $path.$pathCommonItems."commonItems/";` and then call it like `include($pathCommonItems."header.php");` ? Because it's not working :(

Comment: No, use : `$pathCommonItems = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'commonItems/header.php';`

Comment: Actually I did something similar: `$pathParent = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` and then `include($pathParent.'commonItems/header.php');` but still doesn't work.. Which makes sense because $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does not give me the / at the end... :)